# Which is the last commit for version 4.5.3.3 of EPPlus?

Tags: epplus, epplus-4

I am looking for the last LGPL version of EPPlus, namely 4.5.3.3.

Digging through Github I didn't find it.

[Nuget does not point](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/4.5.3.3) to the exact code/commit.

It is a license question, like if I want to fork the last LGPL version.

#### Update

Found it at https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/commit/55c5ba6169eaa6ae7867fefb36a84cc0b28be85a

commit 55c5ba6169eaa6ae7867fefb36a84cc0b28be85a